# JSON CSS parser

Tags: javascript, css, json, parsing, recursion

my recursive function is breaking and I cannot figure out why. I am trying to write a parser for json to css with barebone javascript and can't seem to wrap my head around why my function doesn't work. Can anyone lend me a hand?

In css you would get elements that are children of that particular element you are addressing with something like this

```
#nav li{
  some style here
}
```

Trying to manipulate the same thing in javascript only it doesn't work. My code works fine for simple selectors so far.

```
var json = {
    "body" : {
        "background": "#303030",
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
    },
    "#nav": {
        "li": {
            "display": "inline-block",
            "list-styles": "none",
            "margin-right": "10px",
            "padding": "10px, 10px"
        }
    }
}
// How to use:
// json is an obj
// body is a selector
// background is a property belong to a selector
// #303030 is a value for the property


//apply css changes to document without writing any css
//by default the first values are
//               selector = background
//               parent   = document
//               object   = json
function styleApply(selector, parent, object){
    var element, onSelector, signal;

    //checks the first character of the selector and grabs element from page depending on what type of element it is
    switch(selector[0]){
        case ".":
            element= parent.getElementsByClassName(selector.substring(1));
            newParent = element[0]; //checks to see what is in the first index of the obtained element
            break;
        case "#":
            element= parent.getElementById(selector.substring(1));
            newParent = element;
            break;
        default:
            element= parent.getElementsByTagName(selector);
            newParent = element[0];
            break;
    }

    //only works if there is actually an element in the page corresponding with the selector
    if(newParent != null){ 
        //loops through all elements with the same selector or in the case of id just does one loop
        for(var i=0; i<element.length; i++){ 

            //loops through all properties in the selector
            for (var property in object[selector]){
                //grabs the associated value with the selector could be string or object
                var value= object[selector][property];

                //if it is a string it is a style, if it is an object, it is targeting the elements inside the current selector only
                if(typeof(value) === "string"){
                    element[i].style.setProperty(property, value);
                }else{

/*I am breaking my code right here*/

                    //reusing the same function, this time selector is equal to property for the case of nav, it is the element 'li'
                    //newParent is the element who is a parent of the current element (e.g 'nav' is parent of 'li')
                    //value is the new object that is replacing json, 
                    styleApply(property, newParent, value); //since value is an object it did not pass the string test and now the new object is value
/*Problem ends here */


                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

my code for looping over all the values in json
for (var selector in json){
    styleApply(selector, document, json);
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection. You need to wrap it in an array.

Comment: When you call your function recursively, you need to pass `element[i]` as the new parent, not `newParent`.

Comment: YAY Thanks a lot Barmar, I managed to shorten my code and got the inheritor working! and thanks xbonez for looking over my work. One extra change I made is in my value = object[selector]
I needed to go back one param to replicate the structure of my json

Comment: Object iteration order is implementation dependent and browsers are not reliable with this, so this approach will not work consistently with css rules where order is important

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to look into json to write a cleaner css than straight up concatenating strings and numbers together. Instead of applying the style directly to each element, I put them into a `<style>` element, which makes it easier to change throughout the lifetime of the page. It's also capable of targeting pseudo-elements such as :before, which I used.

Anyway, here's the function:

```
// convert json to css
function jsonToCss(obj) {
    var x, finalStr=''
    for (x in obj) {
        var y, decStr=''
        for (y in obj[x]) {
            decStr+= y + ':' + obj[x][y] + ';'
        }
        finalStr+= x + '{' + decStr + '}'
    }
    return finalStr
}
```

As the function only recurses through two levels (one for the selectors and one for the declarations) your json needs to be modified as follows:

```
var json = {
    "body" : {
        "background": "#303030",
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
    },
    "#nav li": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "list-styles": "none",
        "margin-right": "10px",
        "padding": "10px, 10px"
    }
}
```

Feed that into the function and you get the following string:

```
body{background:#303030;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}#nav li{display:inline-block;list-styles:none;margin-right:10px;padding:10px, 10px;}
```

Which you can then place into a style element. I haven't validated the strings produced by the function to see if it's well-formed but it works quite well on my end.

Answer (score 0):

> It is a short little code I read about parsing json into css and I wanted to try it out
>
> -- selectors are referring to css selectors that you write in json
>
> -- parent starts out referring to the document as in the Document object model in javascript
>
> -- object is the json object being passed in
>
> please do correct me again if I misuse any jargon

```
function styleApply(selector, parent, object){
    var element, onSelector, signal;
    
    switch(selector[0]){
        case ".":
            element= parent.getElementsByClassName(selector.substring(1));
            break;
        case "#":
            element= [parent.getElementById(selector.substring(1))];
            break;
        default:
            element= parent.getElementsByTagName(selector);
            break;
    }
    
    if(element[0] != null){
        for(var i=0; i<element.length; i++){ 
            for (var property in object[selector]){
            
                var value= object[selector][property];

                if(typeof(value) === "string"){
                    element[i].style.setProperty(property, value);
                }else{
                    styleApply(property, element[i], object[selector]);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```